# How can I set a fix size of a javafx column?

Tags: javafx

I am new to javafx and I try to create a table. Currently it is possible to change the columns of this table. But I would like the width of the columns to be fixed and not changeable by the user.
What I have tried is the following:

`column.setResizable(false)`

But this does not lead to the desired result (which I do not understand).
I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] of `setResizable` not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setMinWidth and setMaxWidth to the same value?

Comment: Thank you! I had not thought about that. That works!

Answer (score 0):

If `<TableColumn fx:id="column" resizable="false" text:"column1"/>` is written to the .fxml file, it works too.

Comment: That indicates the `TableColumn` you invoke `setResizable` on in code is not the same instance created by FXML. A [mre] could help us help you.